# unified diff for code block changes

Tags: diff

I have old program code like this:

```
X {
  Y {
    A;
    B {
      C;
    }
  }
  1;
}
```

and a new version where one block is changed like this:

```
X {
  Z {
    q {
      x;
    }
    y;
  }
  2;
}
```

Now when I do unified diff, then I get:

```
 X {
-  Y {
-    A;
-    B {
-      C;
+  Z {
+    q {
+      x;
     }
+    y;
   }
+  2;
 }
```

What I do not like is that the "Y" block is totally changed to "Z" but diff shows "}" as unchanged lines between other changes and it makes big block changes not well readable where the whole removed and added block are sliced with "}" and not together as one big block.

Is there any way to get diff output something like this?

```
 X {
-  Y {
-    A;
-    B {
-      C;
-    }
-  }
+  Z {
+    q {
+      x;
+    }
+    y;
+  }
+  2;
 }
```